# FTP Permissions Not set

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, ftp

I just installed vsftpd into my Raspberry Pi, and have a working FTP and SSH connection. My FTP opens into my `pi` user home, and from there I navigate to `/var/www` , this is not a problem. The thing is that when I upload a file, its permissions are set to `rw-r-x--` meaning that I can't access them from a browser (like `index.html` for example), and Apache returns a Denied error.

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following in your `vsftpd.conf`:

```
file_open_mode=0644
local_umask=022
```

From the `man` page:

> **file_open_mode**
>       The permissions with which uploaded files are created. Umasks are applied on top of this value. You may wish to change to 0777 if you
>   want uploaded files to be executable.
>
> Default: 0666

and:

> **local_umask**
>       The value that the umask for file creation is set to for local users. NOTE! If you want to specify octal values, remember the "0"
>   prefix otherwise the value will be treated as a base 10 integer!
>
> Default: 077

With these set, you should get permissions of `0644` or `rw-r--r--`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! However I have no idea what `umask` is, I'm guessing user mask? But what does it do?

Comment: `umask` sets the default permissions on a new file.  There's a good article about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).